# l value required as increment operand

Tags: c, increment, lvalue, rvalue, pre-increment

Can somebody explain the compilation error in the program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   printf("%d", ++(-i));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-i` is simply not an lvalue, but an rvalue.

Comment: `++(-i)` => `++(-10)` : It is not possible to assign the result of the increment to -10.

Comment: It's interesting how this question is an almost _exact_ duplicate to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230274/lvalue-required-as-increment-operand-error)… except that it's ported from C++ to C.

Comment: @DarkDust: Now it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `-i` is an r-value, not an l-value.  You can't increment r-values with the `++` or `--` operators; you can only increment an l-value.

Roughly, an l-value could appear on the LHS (left-hand side) of an assignment.  You could not write:

```
-i = -i + 1;
```

For the same reason, you cannot write `++(-i)`.